# Assests + MSM + Indexing new site = Uh oh!

Tags: assets, multi-site-manager

SO, I have assets installed on site1 - works great.
I add site 2, index the uploads, cool.

I can add images in the module, but when I try to add images within an entry, the buttons are grayed back. Any idea why I can't add images within an entry in site2?

Comment: Anything? I'm hoping to get this resolved this week. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any script loading errors in the JS console of something like Firebug or Chrome's Inspector when you are in an entry on the Control Panel?

Comment: This is odd. I can add images now (not sure why) -- but I can't add new folders. Thank you for commenting, diemer, does anyone (esp PT people ) have any idea?

Comment: OK strike that -- now I selected another entry from another channel and I can not upload images. Something is crazy here!

Comment: Do you have at least one file upload preference created on the Site in question? If not, can you try adding one and see if that helps? :)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, and it was a simple solution for my set up. I had to copy the themes folder from site 1 into site 2, including third party and EE system cp themes etc, with site_themes being the only folder unique to site 2.

Bit of a pain because of the need to sync the two themes folders manually when adding new add-ons and updates, but since it's only for my occasional MSM site I can handle that.

It is also possible to link to assets using the site 1  links if you want to keep a single themes folder, as long as you don't mind the site 1 links in source code of site 2.

Comment: I did, but honestly I don't remember the solution. I think maybe I had a caching issue + permissions may have not been set properly for site2.